# SQL - Include a not exists line in a aggregation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a order table and I'm aggregation this table by this query:

```
SELECT dtdate, idsku, sum(vlorder) as vlorder, sum(qtditem) as qtditem
FROM order
GROUP BY dtdate, idsku
```

And I'm getting this results:

```
dtdate  idsku   vlorder qtditem
01/01/2016  1   4   8
02/01/2016  1   5   10
03/01/2016  1   3   6
04/01/2016  1   2   4
05/01/2016  1   3   6
06/01/2016  1   1   2
```

But, I don't have results for 07/01/2016 and idsku = 1 because doesn't exists on the database (sounds dummy). And I have to include this "empty" line 07/01/2016 1 0 0, like this:

```
dtdate  idsku   vlorder qtditem
01/01/2016  1   4   8
02/01/2016  1   5   10
03/01/2016  1   3   6
04/01/2016  1   2   4
05/01/2016  1   3   6
06/01/2016  1   1   2
07/01/2016  1   0   0
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You should probably use a calendar table (google it), and `left join` to that to get all dates. With `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` you can change `NULL` to `0`

Comment: I am doing this and getting 07/01/2016 Null Null Null .I don't have idsku in the line to coalesce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Postgres, you can use `generate_series()`:

```
select g.mon, o.idsku, 
        sum(o.vlorder) as vlorder, sum(o.qtditem) as qtditem
from generate_series('2016-01-01'::timestamp, '2016-07-01'::timestamp,
                     interval '1' month) g(mon) left join
     orders o
     on o.dtdate = g.mon
group by g.mon, idsku;
```

If your dates are not on the first of the month, then you can use `date_trunc('day', o.dtdate) = g.mon`.

Comment: I don't have the '2016-07-01' date on order, so my idsku is null and I have to know the value. Is possible?

Comment: @gabriel.almeida . . . I don't understand your comment.